# JAVAFX in android studio

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports

Is there a way that i can directly install gluon plugin to android studio.
I would like to use scene javafx in my project with the help of scene builder
i am searching for dependencies for javafx to import in my **gradle**.

I don't know what is possible and what's not possible with these so many IDE's,plugins,Platforms etc.,

Comment: Have a look at the [Kokos sample](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples) from JavaFXPorts, and also to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948461/how-can-i-use-a-javafx-activity-in-an-android-project-kokos-sample-project/41984835#41984835). It shows how you can include JavaFX in an Android project.